# Как обратиться к значению словаря в цикле for [django, python, html]

Tags: python, django

Я передаю `context` в html и надо вывести значения в цикле - по цифре ключу.

не выводится. как обратиться к значению словаря в цикле?

**print context**

`context = {'tag': 'fast', 'view': <orders.views.OrderAddView object at 0x0000000005AB30A0>, 1: <class 'clients.forms.RelatedAddForm'>, 2: <class 'clients.forms.RelatedAddForm2'>, 'count_form': range(1, 3)}`

**html**

```
 <form action="{% url 'order_add' tag %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for x in count_form %}
            {{ x.as_p }} - это не работает
        {% endfor %}
        {{ 1.as_p }} - это работает
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Добавить заказ</button>
    </form>
```

то есть как в цикле обратиться к значениям 1,2 итд - `1: <class 'clients.forms.RelatedAddForm'>`?

возможно надо к в цикле указать `{{ context[x].as_p }}`? как это сделать?

Comment: решение https://stackoverflow.com/a/66655125/9653855